# Re-arranging values in a table

Tags: r, unix, dataframe

I have a huge table with unarranged data in its rows (relative to the name of the columns). The table looks something like this:

```
A  B  C
A1 B1 C1
A2 C2 NA
A3 C3 B3
NA B4 C4
```

I was wondering if there is way to re-arrange this table so that all values that start with "A" will be on the first column and all values that start with "B" will be on the second column and so on...

The desired outcome will be something like this:

```
A  B  C
A1 B1 C1
A2 NA C2
A3 B3 C3
NA B4 C4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one efficient way to approach it with `data.table`

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df1)  # assign data table by reference
# melt df1 data with unique id for each row
df1 <- melt( data = df1[, id := .I], measure.vars = setdiff( names(df1), 'id' ))  
# assign variable = NA which has value = NA, and variable = column_names for other values
df1[, variable := gsub("[0-9]", "", value)]
# rearrange df1 into multiple columns and remove NA and id columns
dcast(df1, "id ~ variable", value.var = "value")[, `:=` (`NA` = NULL, id = NULL ) ][]
```

Output:

```
#     A  B  C
# 1: A1 B1 C1
# 2: A2 NA C2
# 3: A3 B3 C3
# 4: NA B4 C4
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
           A  B  C
           A1 B1 C1
           A2 C2 NA
           A3 C3 B3
           NA B4 C4",
           header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**EDIT:**

using the data above.

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df1)[, D:= c( NA_character_)] # add column D
df1[, id := .I] # add unique id for each row
nm <- copy( setdiff( names(df1), 'id' ) ) # get column names and remove id
df1 <- dcast( data = melt( data = df1, measure.vars = nm)[, variable := gsub("[0-9]", "", value)],
              formula = "id ~ variable", 
              # subsetting is done because, two NA values are passed to the aggregate function two times ( column D and A for row-4; column C and D for row-2 ). 
              # you can check it using this: function(x) print(x)
              fun = function(x)x[1],  
              value.var = "value",
              fill = NA_character_ )[, id := NULL ][]
# check for number of columns
if( ncol(df1) > length(nm) ){
  df1[, `NA` := NULL ] # remove extra NA column
  nm <- setdiff(names(df1), 'NA') # remove extra column name: NA
} 
# rename columns efficiently by reference
setnames( df1, nm)
```

**output**

```
print(df1)
#     A  B  C  D
# 1: A1 B1 C1 NA
# 2: A2 NA C2 NA
# 3: A3 B3 C3 NA
# 4: NA B4 C4 NA
```

Comment: The script worked for the above example. However for a larger dataset (which is my case the script didn't work). For example, if I add a column "D" to the above table with NA values in it, the output  looked something like this: A B C
1: 1 1 1  
2: 1 0 1  
3: 1 1 1  
4: 0 1 1

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

```
read.table(text = "
A  B  C
A1 B1 C1
A2 C2 NA
A3 C3 B3
NA B4 C4",
header = T) -> df

dfnew <- matrix(c(paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 4), seq(1:4))), ncol = 3, nrow = 4)
dfnew[!dfnew %in% sort(as.character(unlist(df)))] <- NA
dfnew

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A1" "B1" "C1"
[2,] "A2" NA   "C2"
[3,] "A3" "B3" "C3"
[4,] NA   "B4" "C4"
```

In short: create a new matrix that contains all possible combinations of letters and numbers, and set those to NA which are not in the original table.

Answer (score 1):

For each row this finds, in `df[1,]`, the first letter of each element, and moves that element to the same column as the match found in `df[1,]`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pmap(~{ x <- c(...)
          ind <- map_dbl(substr(x, 1, 1), ~grep(.x, df[1,])[1]) %>% 
                  .[!is.na(.)]
          rep(NA, 3) %>% 
            `[<-`(ind, x[!is.na(x)])}) %>% 
  do.call(what = rbind) %>% 
  as.data.frame
#     V1   V2 V3
# 1   A1   B1 C1
# 2   A2 <NA> C2
# 3   A3   B3 C3
# 4 <NA>   B4 C4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pmatch` into an `apply` call, and then reconvert as a `data.frame` with proper names:

```
abc <- names(df)
setNames(as.data.frame(t(
  apply(df,1,function(x) x[pmatch(abc,x)])
  )),abc)

#      A    B  C
# 1   A1   B1 C1
# 2   A2 <NA> C2
# 3   A3   B3 C3
# 4 <NA>   B4 C4
```

This is how `pmatch` works here:

```
x <- c("A2","C2",NA)
x[pmatch(abc,x)]
# [1] "A2" NA   "C2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really bad solution:

```
rm(list=ls())

dataset<-read.csv("exampleSO.csv",header = F); 

a<-as.matrix.data.frame(dataset);

loc<-as.vector(a[1,]); 

ourM<-a[2:5,]; 

x<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=4,ncol=3)

for (i in 1:nrow(ourM)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(ourM)){
    place<-which(substr(ourM[i,j],1,1)==loc)
    x[i,place] <- ourM[i,j]
  }
}

as.matrix.data.frame(rbind(loc,x))

#result 
     [,1][,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C" 
[2,] "A1" "B1" "C1"
[3,] "A2" NA   "C2"
[4,] "A3" "B3" "C3"
[5,] NA   "B4" "C4"
```

Replace exampleSO.csv with your `.csv` containing the data or any variable that contains that dataframe.

Tell me if it works!